# Geometry to JumpTask.IconResourcePath

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, jump-list

im wondering, is there a way that you can **bind JumpTask.IconResourcePath with a Geometry**. Without needing to create an ico or dll file to read it from. Thank you.

My code:

```xml
<Application x:Class="Example.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SecureVast"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
 <JumpList.JumpList>
        <JumpList ShowRecentCategory="True"
                ShowFrequentCategory="True">
            <JumpTask Title="Example" Description="Open Example App." ApplicationPath="C:\Windows\notepad.exe" 
             IconResourcePath="{Binding ExampleGeometry}"/>
             <!-- Note: This is not actual working code, this is just what I want to achive -->
    </JumpList.JumpList>
</Application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No, `IconResourcePath` is a `string` property that should be set to a *path* to a resource that contains the icon.

You cannot set it to a `Geometry`.